# How to set datepicker value to selected date android

Tags: android, datepicker

I have value Birthdate but I want to display/selected in the datepicker dialog the birthdate. for example March 1 1997  - > This date is selected in the datepicker dialog. I tried but only goes with error. I cant find where the error is.

**CODE:**

```
public void setDate(){

        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showBirthDate);


        //get birthday
        int id = Integer.parseInt(dbhandler.getLatestProfileId());
        String data=dbhandler.getBirthdate(id);

        //split string for date
        String[] parts = data.split("/");
        month = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

        //current
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        showDate(year, month, day);

    }
```

Comment: Have you check the format your date is using

Answer (score 1):

You can set the date in date picker dialog during initialization as follow:

```
  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                context,
                null,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
```